# Whether matrix exponential from skew-symmetric 3x3 matrices to SO(3) is local homeomorphism?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation, rotations

$SO(3)$ denotes [3x3 rotation matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO%283%29). This is [Lie group, with corresponding Lie algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_group#The_Lie_algebra_associated_with_a_Lie_group) being $\mathrm{Skew}_3$, the space of 3x3 skew-symmetric matrices. The link between them is the [matrix exponential map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_exponential)
$$ \exp:\mathrm{Skew}_3 \to SO(3),\qquad \exp(A)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} A^n=I+A+\frac{1}{2}A^2+\ldots$$

[I understand that](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Lie_theory) $\exp$ is a [local diffeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_diffeomorphism) in a neighborhood of zero matrix. I wonder:

1. Why $\exp$ is not a local diffeomorphism everywhere in $\mathrm{Skew}_3$?
2. Whether $\exp$ is a local homeomorphism everywhere in $\mathrm{Skew}_3$ and why?

If possible please provide a reference.

Comment: Chapters 2 and 3 of B.C. Hall's book "Lie Groups, Lie Algebras and Representations: An Elementary Introduction" (Springer) has a good overview on this matter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define a norm on $\mathrm{Skew}_3$ by
$$
\left\|\begin{bmatrix}0 & -c & b \\ c & 0 & -a \\ -b & a & 0\end{bmatrix}\right\| \;=\; \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}.
$$
Then, for any $A \in \mathrm{Skew}_3$, the norm $\|A\|$ corresponds to the angle of rotation of $\exp(A)$.  Specifically, $\exp(A)$ is a rotation by an angle of $\|A\|$ around an axis parallel to the vector $(a,b,c)$.

Note then that if $A\in\mathrm{Skew}_3$ and $\|A\| = 2\pi$, then $\exp(A)$ is equal to the identity matrix.  That is, the entire sphere of radius $2\pi$ centered at the origin in $\mathrm{Skew}_3$ maps to the identity matrix under $\exp$.  Thus $\exp$ is not a local diffeomorphism (or even a local homeomorphism) at points on this sphere.  The same holds true along the sphere of radius $4\pi$, the sphere of radius $6\pi$, and so forth.

By the way, it should be apparent that $\exp$ is a local homeomorphism near zero.  In particular, the entire open ball of radius $\pi$ maps homeomorphically into $SO(3)$, and its image consists of all rotations by angles less than $\pi$.  However, $\exp$ is not one-to-one on the boundary of this ball, since $\exp(A) = \exp(-A)$ for any $A\in\mathrm{Skew}_3$ with $\|A\| = \pi$.

Comment: I would like more information on maximal radius of the open ball where $\exp$ is local homeomorphism, but in order not to change the original question, which you have nicely answered, I have cast another question on http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634231/neighborhood-of-zero-radius-where-exp-skew3x3-so3-is-local-homeomorphism