# Prove where exp: Skew($3\times 3$) $\rightarrow SO(3)$ is local homeomorphism

Tags: differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, exponentiation, rotations

The [matrix exponential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Exponential_map) on skew-symmetric $3\times3$ matrices onto [$SO(3)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_group_SO%283%29) is not [local homeomorphism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Local_homeomorphism) everywhere. [I have been instructed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/634116/whether-matrix-exponential-from-skew-symmetric-3x3-matrices-to-so3-is-local-ho) that one problem is with the spheres of radius $2n\pi$ ($n\in\mathbb{N}$) in the scaled [Frobenius norm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) $\|\,\|=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\|\,\|_F$. As I understand this [$\exp$ is $C^\infty$ smooth](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_map#Properties) and injection on the open ball of radius $\pi$.

I would like to know what is the radius of the largest open ball around zero where this matrix $\exp$ is a local homeomorphism, or maybe even diffeomorphism? Even better an explanation, a proof or a reference to the proof should be given.

In essence, I see there needs to be shown that for every $X$ in such a ball, the differential (pushforward) $\mathrm{d}_{\exp(X)}$ is linear isomorphism. I lack the knowledge of differential geometry to proceed.

Comment: The spheres of radius $2\pi n$ are the only problem.  The exponential function is a local diffeomorphism everywhere else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the sketch of differential on a smooth map between manifolds from Wikipedia:[image: Differential Df maps from tangent space at X to tangent space at f(X)]

In this case we have 
$$
\begin{array}{cccc}
 & \mbox{Domain} & \mbox{Mapping} & \mbox{Target set}\\
\mbox{Manifold} & M=\mathbb{R}_{{\rm skew}}^{3\times3} & \overset{\varphi(X)=\exp X}{\longrightarrow} & N=SO(3)\\
\mbox{Tangent space} & T_{X}M=\mathbb{R}_{{\rm skew}}^{3\times3} & \overset{\mathrm{d}_{\varphi(X)}}{\longrightarrow} & T_{\varphi(X)}N=?
\end{array}
$$

[Differential](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushforward_%28differential%29) of $\varphi$
  at $X$
  is a linear map $\mathrm{d}_{\varphi(X)}:T_{X}M\to T_{\varphi(X)}N$
  that can be computed like this 
$${\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}\underset{\begin{array}{c}
\uparrow\\
\blacksquare
\end{array}}{\left(\,\gamma'(0)\,\right)}=\left(\varphi\circ\gamma\right)'(0)$$
  where $\gamma$
  is a curve such that $\gamma(0)=X$. As a linear map, the differential is fully determined by it's action on a basis in $T_{X}M$. Therefore the symbol $\blacksquare$ denotes a place where we want to insert one by one elements of a basis for $T_{X}M$. If $\{{\bf b}_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a basis in $T_{X}M$, and ${\bf v}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}{\bf b}_{i}$ where $v_{i}$ are scalars (coordinates), then we know that ${\rm d}_{\varphi\left(X\right)}{\bf v}=\sum_{i=1}^{n}v_{i}{\rm d}_{\varphi\left(X\right)}{\bf b}_{i}$. To check that ${\rm d}_{\varphi\left(X\right)}$ is an isomorphism we only need to check that $\{{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}{\bf b}_{i}\}_{i=1}^{n}$ is a linearly independent set.

Let us use the [Rodrigues' rotation formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodrigues%27_rotation_formula) to ease the computation (for $B\in\mathbb{R}_{{\rm skew}}^{3\times3}$): 
$$
\exp B={\rm Id}+\frac{\sin\left\Vert B\right\Vert }{\left\Vert B\right\Vert }B+\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert B\right\Vert }{\left\Vert B\right\Vert ^{2}}B^{2}\in SO(3)\mbox{.}
$$

My first try was to insert the elements of the canonical orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}_{{\rm skew}}^{3\times3}$ in $\blacksquare$. We can do that by choosing $\gamma_{i}(t)=X+tA_{i}$, so that $\gamma_{i}'(0)=A_{i}$ where
$$
A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0\\
 & 0 & -1\\
 & 1 & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad A_{2}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 &  & 1\\
 & 0\\
-1 &  & 0
\end{array}\right),\quad A_{1}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -1\\
1 & 0\\
 &  & 0
\end{array}\right).
$$
Then, for $X=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -x_{3} & x_{2}\\
x_{3} & 0 & -x_{1}\\
-x_{2} & x_{1} & 0
\end{array}\right)$
  we have (using the Rodrigues' formula) 
$$
{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A_{i}=\frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\exp\left(X+tA_{i}\right)_{t=0}=\frac{f(\left\Vert X\right\Vert )x_{i}}{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }X+\frac{\sin\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }A_{i}+\frac{g(\left\Vert X\right\Vert )x_{i}}{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }X+\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}}2X.A_{i}
$$
where $f(u)\overset{{\rm def}}{=}\frac{u\cos u-\sin u}{u^{2}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(\frac{\sin u}{u}\right)$ and $g(u)\overset{{\rm def}}{=}\frac{u\sin u-2+2\cos u}{u^{3}}=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}u}\left(\frac{1-\cos u}{u^{2}}\right)$. Within $X.A_{i}$, the dot stands for matrix multiplication. Unfortunately, I am not able to see that $\{{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A_{i}\}_{i=1}^{3}$ is linearly independent, unless $X=O$. It seems as if plugging the easiest choices into $\blacksquare$
  resulted with a complicated right hand side in the same formula. But at least we have proved that ${\rm d}_{\exp}$
  is isomorphism at $X=O$, that is $\exp$
  is local diffeomorphism at $O\in\mathbb{R}_{{\rm Skew}}^{3\times3}$.

Therefore, I started again from the beginning, this time trying to choose a basis that will result in the simplest result on the right hand side (after differentiation). Provided $X\in\mathbb{R}_{{\rm skew}}^{3\times3}$
  is set, note that for each $y\in\mathbb{R}^{3}$
  we have $X.y=\left(\begin{array}{c}
x_{1}\\
x_{2}\\
x_{3}
\end{array}\right)\times y$
  (with $X.y$
  I denoted matrix multiplying a vector). Provided with $X\neq O$, I choose $a=\left(\begin{array}{c}
a_{1}\\
a_{2}\\
a_{3}
\end{array}\right)$ and $b=\left(\begin{array}{c}
b_{1}\\
b_{2}\\
b_{3}
\end{array}\right)$ such that $\left\Vert a\right\Vert =1=\left\Vert b\right\Vert$   and $a\times\frac{x}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }=b$, $\frac{x}{\left\Vert x\right\Vert }\times b=a$ (we have $a\bot b$, $a\bot x$ and $b\bot x$). Let 
$$A=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -a_{3} & a_{2}\\
a_{3} & 0 & -a_{1}\\
-a_{2} & a_{1} & 0
\end{array}\right)\mbox{ and }B=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
0 & -b_{3} & b_{2}\\
b_{3} & 0 & -b_{1}\\
-b_{2} & b & 0
\end{array}\right)\mbox{.}
$$
Then we have $A.y=a\times y$ and $B.y=b\times y$. Now I will use different $\gamma_{i}$, 
$$
\gamma_{1}(t)=X+tX,\gamma_{1}'(0)=X,\quad\gamma_{2}(t)=X+tA,\gamma'(0)=A,\quad\gamma_{2}(t)=X+tB,\gamma'(0)=B\mbox{.}
$$
We can check that $\{X,A,B\}$ is orthogonal base in $\mathbb{R}^{3\times3}$ using the following inner product on matrices: $A:B=\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}\left(A^{T}.B\right)$, where ${\rm Tr}$ denotes the matrix trace. We have $A:B=a\cdot b=0$, $A:X=a\cdot x=0$ and $B:X=b\cdot x=0$ (dot denotes the ordinary vector scalar product). Therefore, $A\bot B$, $A\bot X$ and $B\bot X$.

Let us also here establish some other facts that will be used later. Let us show that $\{X,\, A,\, B,\, X^{2},\, X.A,\, X.B\}$ is linearly independent (evenmore orthogonal) set. We have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
x\times\left(x\times\left(x\times y\right)\right) & = & x\times\left(x\left(x\cdot y\right)-y\left(x\cdot x\right)\right)\qquad\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\mbox{vector}\\
\mbox{triple}\\
\mbox{product}
\end{array}\right\} \\
 &=& \left(x\cdot y\right)x\times x-\left(x\cdot x\right)x\times y\qquad\left\{ \begin{array}{c}
\mbox{distributive}\\
\mbox{property}
\end{array}\right\} \\
 &=& -\left\Vert x\right\Vert ^{2}\, x\times y
\end{eqnarray*}
so we conclude $X^{3}=-\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}X\in\mathbb{R}_{{\rm Skew}}^{3\times3}$. Therefore $X:X^{2}=\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}\left(X^{T}.X^{2}\right)=\frac{1}{2}{\rm Tr}\left(-X^{3}\right)=0$. On the other hand, by using vector triple product and orthogonality between $x$, $a$ and $b$
\begin{eqnarray*}
X^{2}.A.y &=& x\times\left(x\times\left(a\times y\right)\right) =x\times\left((x\cdot y)\, a\right)=\left\Vert x\right\Vert (x\cdot y)\, b,\\
X.B.y &=& x\times\left(b\times y\right) =(x\cdot y)\, b\mbox{ .}
\end{eqnarray*}
Therefore $X^{2}.A=X.B$, so together with $X:X.A=-{\rm Tr}\left(X^{2}.A\right)=-X^{2}:A$ we get $X:X.A=-X^{2}:A=-{\rm Tr}\left(X.B\right)=X:B=0$. In the same manner we get that all pairs in $\{X,\, A,\, B,\, X^{2},\, X.A,\, X.B\}$ are orthogonal.

Back to our differential, from Rodrigues' formula we get 
\begin{eqnarray*}
{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}X &=& \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\exp\left(X+tX\right)_{t=0}=\left(f(\left\Vert X\right\Vert )\left\Vert X\right\Vert +\frac{\sin\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }+g(\left\Vert X\right\Vert )\left\Vert X\right\Vert \right)X+2\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}}X^{2},\\
{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A &=& \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\exp\left(X+tA\right)_{t=0}=\frac{\sin\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }A+2\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}}X.A,\\
{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}B &=& \frac{{\rm d}}{{\rm d}t}\exp\left(X+tB\right)_{t=0}=\frac{\sin\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert }B+2\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}}X.B\,\mbox{.}
\end{eqnarray*}
The final point to see is that $\{{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}X,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}B\}$ is linearly independent set, evenmore orthogonal. Notice that each one out of $\{{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}X,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}B\}$ is a linear combination of two different elements out of six in orthogonal set $\{X,\, A,\, B,\, X^{2},\, X.A,\, X.B\}$. Therefore, unless one of the elements in $\{{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}X,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A,\,{\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}B\}$ is actually a trivial combination, we have proved that ${\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}$ is isometry, that is $\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism. Note that ${\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}A=O={\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}B$ if and only if $\left\Vert X\right\Vert =n\pi,\, n\in\mathbb{N}$. 
Furthermore, ${\rm d}_{\varphi(X)}X$ can not become zero unless the factor $\frac{1-\cos\left\Vert X\right\Vert }{\left\Vert X\right\Vert ^{2}}$ becomes zero, which can not happen when $\left\Vert X\right\Vert \neq n\pi,\, n\in\mathbb{N}$. Together with what we already have for $X=0$, we arrived at the conclusion that $\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^{3\times 3}_{\rm Skew}$, except on the spheres of radius $2n\pi$, $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I am inexperienced in differential geometry calculations, so please do not hesitate to be hairsplitting. I would like to get this right.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an almost purely computational answer, avoiding the double covering of the rotation group $SO(3)$ by $S^3$. Re-writing seemed likely to be easier (and possibly clearer) than retro-fitting additional explanation in service of an apparently unhelpful geometric picture. I've wikified the original response (with its geometric/conceptual approach) in case someone someday would like to have a go at clarifying the details.

To each unit vector $\mathbf{u} = (a, b, c)$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$, associate the skew-symmetric matrix
$$
U = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr@{}}
0 & -c & b \\
c & 0 & -a \\
-b & a & 0
\end{array}\right],
$$
and let $S^2$ denote the set of all such matrices. The vector $\mathbf{u}$ spans the null space of $U$, and hence is a $1$-eigenvector of $\exp(tU) = I + tU + \dots$ for all real $t$, i.e., spans the axis of the rotation $\exp(tU)$. Geometrically, $U$ is the infinitesimal counterclockwise rotation about $\mathbf{u}$ of angular speed
$$
\left\lVert \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp(tU)\right\rVert
  = \|U\| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(U^tU)} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2} = 1.
$$

A non-zero matrix in the open ball of radius $2\pi$ is written uniquely as $tU$, with $U$ a matrix of scaled Frobenius norm one and $0 < t < 2\pi$. By the preceding calculation, $\exp(tU)$ is the counterclockwise rotation about $\mathbf{u}$ by angle $t$.

**Claim 1**: $\exp$ is a local differmorphism on the ball of radius $2\pi$. To prove this, it suffices to show that if $H$ is an open hemisphere of $S^2$, then the map $\Phi:H \times (0, 2\pi) \to SO(3)$ defined by $\Phi(U, t) = \exp(tU)$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image.

For longitude $\theta$ and colatitude $\phi$ between $0$ and $\pi$, consider the orthonormal basis
$$
\mathbf{e}_1 = \left[\begin{matrix}
  \cos\theta \sin\phi \\
  \sin\theta \sin\phi \\
  \cos\phi
\end{matrix}\right],\qquad
\mathbf{e}_2 = \left[\begin{matrix}
  \sin\theta \\
  -\cos\theta \\
  0
\end{matrix}\right],\qquad
\mathbf{e}_3 = \left[\begin{matrix}
  \cos\theta \cos\phi \\
  \sin\theta \cos\phi \\
  -\sin\phi
\end{matrix}\right].
$$
Calling $U$ the $3 \times 3$ skew-symmetric matrix associated to the unit vector $\mathbf{e}_1$, we have
\begin{align*}
\Phi(U, t) = \exp(tU)
  &= \left[\begin{matrix}
  \mathbf{e}_1 &
  (\cos t)\mathbf{e}_2 + (\sin t)\mathbf{e}_3 &
  -(\sin t)\mathbf{e}_2 + (\cos t)\mathbf{e}_3
\end{matrix}\right] \left[\begin{matrix}
  \mathbf{e}_1^t \\
  \mathbf{e}_2^t \\
  \mathbf{e}_3^t
\end{matrix}\right] \\
  &= \mathbf{e}_1 \mathbf{e}^t
  + (\cos t)(\mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_2^t + \mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_3^t)
  + (\sin t)(\mathbf{e}_3 \mathbf{e}_2^t - \mathbf{e}_2 \mathbf{e}_3^t).
\end{align*}
It is straightforward to check algebraically (and clear geometrically) that $D\Phi(\theta, \phi, t)$ has rank $3$ for $0 < \theta < \pi$, $0 < \phi < \pi$, and $0 < t < 2\pi$. Moreover, $\Phi$ is injective, since each line through the origin of $\mathbf{R}^3$ has at most one representative in an open hemisphere, and the range of rotation angles is less than one full turn. That is, $\Phi:H \times (0, 2\pi) \to SO(3)$ is a diffeomorphism onto its image. Covering $S^2$ by open hemispheres obtained from $H$ by permuting coordinates (and/or reflecting across a coordinate plane) shows that the punctured open ball of radius $2\pi$ in the space of skew-symmetric $3 \times 3$ matrices maps locally diffeomorphically to $SO(3)$ under $\exp$. Since $\exp$ is a local diffeomorphism at the zero matrix, $\exp$ maps the ball of radius $2\pi$ locally diffeomorphically to $SO(3)$.

**Claim 2**: $\exp$ is injective on the open ball of radius $\pi$ (hence maps this ball diffeomorphically to its image), and not on the closed ball of radius $\pi$. This is geometrically clear: two counterclockwise rotations by an angle less than $\pi$ about distinct unit vectors are equal if and only if their axes and angles of rotation coincide, while half-turns about unit vectors $\mathbf{u}$ and $-\mathbf{u}$ are equal.

Comment: You gave me some nice ideas, and actually this answer is closer to what I expected to get (exploring the differential). The main point that I would like to see more thoroughly explained is how $D\Phi(\theta,\phi,t)$ looks like, and why it is a linear isomorphism. Note that $\partial_\theta \Phi$ is a matrix (not a vector), and $D\Phi$ is a linear operator from 3D manifold in matrices to matrices, so I wonder how will the rank be estimated. It seems to me that if the previous is shown clearly, then the same isomorphism property would follow for $\Phi:S^2\times(0,2\pi)\to SO(3)$.

Comment: Could you please hint where does that formula for $\Phi(U,t)=\exp(t U)=\ldots$ come from?

Comment: $D\Phi$ is a little awkward to write out; it can be viewed as a $3\times3\times3$ array, or (identifying square matrices with $\mathbf{R}^9$) as a $9\times3$ matrix. The claim about rank amounts to saying that the three (matrix-valued) partial derivatives are linearly independent at each point of $H\times(0,2\pi)$. This can be verified by looking at suitably-chosen entries (rather than at the complete matrices). If $\phi=0$ or $\phi=\pi$, the rank of $D\Phi$ is not three, so one can't extend the calculation from $H$ to $S^2$. :)

Comment: The matrix $\Phi(U, t)$ "clearly" represents counterclockwise rotation about $\mathbf{e}_1$ by angle $t$. But the argument just before Claim 1 shows that this geometric operation is $\exp(tU)$. :)

Comment: Thanks to your comment, now I am able to see what  $\Phi(U,t)$ is. The singularity for $\phi\in\{0,\pi\}$ I am not able to see, but if it is the case, I believe it has to do with the chosen parametrization of $S^2$, rather than with $\exp$ itself. As you pointed out, I believe that, if the parametrization is changed then the potential singularities are moved away. It would have been great if you would have provided some calculation on the differential. Now that I have seen your answer, I have some ideas myself, so I will provide them in a separate answer.

Comment: You're right about the degeneracy having to do with the parametrization, but that's unavoidable, in that $S^2$ cannot be covered by a single chart. In case it helps, $\mathbf{e}_1$ is the unit vector with longitude $\theta$ and colatitude $\phi$. (When $\phi=0$ or $\pi$, $\mathbf{e}_1$ is the same for all $\theta$.) It's possible to construct such a simple orthonormal frame (and separately, to establish injectivity of $\Phi$) because $\mathbf{e}_1$ lies in an open hemisphere. Using a "larger" chart loses these benefits.

Comment: I think I managed to get over the degeneracies in parametrization. Anyway, I will run another bounty. If I had made mistakes in my answer that could help to reveal them. If there are no new slick answers, I will assign the bounty to you, as you have really helped me.

Comment: Haven't had time to inspect your answer carefully, I'm afraid, but in case it helps: Geometrically, one expects $D\Phi$ to be injective in $H\times(0,2\pi)$ because a small increment in any of $\theta$, $\phi$, or $t$ moves the axis of rotation or the angle of rotation, and these motions are linearly independent in the space of rotations. Algebraically, $D\mathbf{e}_1$ has rank $2$ in $H$ (easy computation), and $D\Phi$ has rank $3$ iff the derivative of the "row matrix" factor of $D\Phi$ has rank $3$ (because the "column" factor obviously has rank $3$).

Comment: Regarding the bounty, I initially saw your question because it was "featured", but would have answered in any case because it's an interesting question. However, it seems I have not definitively answered your question, and I won't be offended if you don't award a bounty to either of my answers. If anything I've posted has been helpful (conceptually or otherwise), that's the "real" reward, i.e., the reason I'm involved at MSE.

Answer (score 3):

The exponential map of $SO(3)$ can be understood geometrically by looking at the double cover $S^3$, a.k.a., the group of unit quaternions under multiplication.

(**Added to incorporate comment clarifications**) A two-sheeted covering map $S^3 \to SO(3)$ may be defined as follows. The adjoint action of $S^3$ on its Lie algebra (the $3$-dimensional space of imaginary quaternions, hereafter denoted $\mathbf{R}^3$) is given by
$$
\operatorname{ad}_{\alpha}(X) = \alpha X \alpha^{-1},\quad
X \in \mathbf{R}^3.
$$
The product $\alpha X \alpha^{-1}$ is an imaginary quaternion that depends linearly on $X$ and has the same length as $X$. That is, $\operatorname{ad}_{\alpha}$ is a linear isometry of $\mathbf{R}^3$, i.e., an element of $O(3)$. Since $S^3$ is connected and the identity of $SO(3)$ is in the image, $\operatorname{ad}(S^3) \subseteq SO(3)$.

Clearly, $\operatorname{ad}$ is a group homomorphism, and $\operatorname{ad}_\alpha = I$ if and only if $\alpha X \alpha^{-1} = X$ for all $X$ in $\mathbf{R}^3$, if and only if the imaginary part of $\alpha$ is zero, if and only if $\alpha = \pm 1$. That is, $\ker(\operatorname{ad}) = \{\pm1\}$, the center of $S^3$.

Let $\alpha = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1 i + \alpha_2 j + \alpha_3 k$ denote a typical element of $S^3$. Since $\operatorname{ad}_{\alpha}(X)$ is a polynomial in the components of $\alpha$, the mapping $\operatorname{ad}:S^3 \to SO(3)$ is smooth.

Direct calculation (taking $\alpha$ to be multiples of $i$, $j$, or $k$) shows that arbitrary rotations about coordinate axes of $\mathbf{R}^3$ are in the image of $\operatorname{ad}$. In particular, $\operatorname{ad}$ induces an isomorphism of Lie algebras (hence is a local diffeomorphism), $\operatorname{ad}$ is surjective (axis rotations generate $SO(3)$), and $S^3/\{\pm1\} \simeq SO(3)$ as Lie groups (isomorphic as groups, diffeomorphic as manifolds). 
(**End of addendum**)

On $S^3$ equipped with the round (i.e., invariant) metric of unit radius, the Lie group exponential map agrees with the Riemannian exponential map, which sends a tangent vector $X$ at $1$ (i.e., a pure imaginary quaternion of norm $\|X\|$) to the geodesic
$$
\gamma(t) = \exp(tX) = \cos\bigl(\|X\| t\bigr) + \frac{\sin\bigl(\|X\| t\bigr)}{\|X\|}X
$$
through $1$ and tangent to $X$. The open ball of radius $\pi$ in the Euclidean norm on $T_1S^3$ clearly maps diffeomorphically into $S^3$ (missing one point, $-1$), and the open ball of radius $\pi/2$ maps diffeomorphically to the open hemisphere of $S^3$ centered at $1$. Since no two points of an open hemisphere are antipodal, the induced map from the ball of radius $\pi/2$ to $S^3/\{\pm1\}$ (i.e., to $SO(3)$ up to scaling, see below) is also a diffeomorphism. No larger open ball maps diffeomorphically into $SO(3)$ under this mapping, since the image of the closed ball of radius $\pi/2$ contains antipodal points, which project to the same point of $SO(3)$.

To get the scaling right in the preceding paragraph, let $a$, $b$, and $c$ be real (not all zero), and let
$$
A = \left[\begin{array}{@{}rrr@{}}
0 & -c & b \\
c & 0 & -a \\
-b & a & 0
\end{array}\right].
$$
The vector $X = (a, b, c)$ spans the null space of $A$, and hence is a $1$-eigenvector of
$$
\exp(tA) = I + tA + \dots
$$
for all real $t$, i.e., spans the axis of rotation of $\exp(tA)$. The angular speed of rotation of $\exp(tA)$ is
$$
\left\lVert \frac{d}{dt}\bigg|_{t=0} \exp(tA)\right\rVert
  = \|A\| = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(A^tA)} = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2 + c^2}.
$$
That is, $\exp(A)$ is rotation about $X$ by oriented angle $\|A\|$ (counterclockwise if $X$ points toward your eye). Consequently, (i) the open ball of radius $\pi$ in this norm maps injectively to $SO(3)$: If $\exp(A_1) = \exp(A_2)$, then the rotation axes $X_1$ and $X_2$ coincide, as do the oriented angles; (ii) the closed ball of radius $\pi$ does not map injectively: rotating by $\pi$ or by $-\pi$ about an axis gives the same element of $SO(3)$. By the preceding paragraph, $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism on the open ball of radius $\pi$ in the scaled Frobenius norm (and a local diffeomorphism on the open ball of radius $2\pi$).

Comment: I am able to visualize that the map $f_1$ from open ball of radius $\pi$ in $T_1 S^3$ is diffeomorphism onto $S^3$ without one point (that is -1). As I see it, the next argument you put, is that $f_2$ from $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ is local diffeomorphism everywhere. Could you please elaborate on $f_2$ more clearly?

Comment: @Mate Kosor: There is a surjective homomorphism from the multiplicative group of unit quaternions $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ with kernel $\{\pm1\}$ (details on request), so $S^3/\{\pm1\}$ and $SO(3)$ are isomorphic as groups. Topologically, $SO(3)$ may therefore be viewed as the set of pairs of antipodal points in $S^3$. Consequently, every open set $U \subset S^3$ contained in some open hemisphere (such as an open hemisphere itself :) maps diffeomorphically into $SO(3)$ under the quotient map.

Comment: Topology and differential geometry are not my stronger side. I am able to comprehend that $S^3 / \{\pm 1\}$ is topologicaly the same as $SO(3)$. I expect it to be so, but I don't see why that map is local diffeomorphism, as there lacks an argument on differentiability. The other thing is, even if there is a map $f_2$ from $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ which is local homeomorphism or diffeomorphism, still it is needed to show that $f_1 \circ f_2 = \exp$, at least as I see it.

Comment: Ah...I'll add these details to the answer when I have time (later today). Briefly, the vector space of imaginary quaternions is $3$-dimensional. If $\alpha \in S^3$ and $x$ is an imaginary quaternion, define $T$ in $SO(3)$ by $T(x) = \alpha x\alpha^{-1}$. The double-covering turns out to be $\alpha \mapsto T$, is a rational function of the components of $\alpha$, and intertwines the respective $\exp$ maps on $S^3$ and $SO(3)$.

Comment: Let me condense what I can see: (1) $ad: S^3\to SO(3)$ is differentiable double cover and $ad: S^3/\{\pm 1\} \to SO(3)$ is diffeomorphism and isomorphism of Lie groups. (2) $\exp$ is diffeomorphism from the open ball of radius $\pi$ in $T_1 S^3 = \mathbb{R}^3 \backsimeq \rm{Skew}(3\times3)$ to $\cal{O}$ where $\cal{O}$ is the set of all rotations except these with angle equal $\pi$ (and any axis). Alternatively, $\cal{O}$ can be $S^3$ without 'equator'. We can extend $\exp$ to be diffeomorpism from open ball of radius $2\pi$ to $S^3$ with -1 missing. (X) How the answer follows from here?

Comment: In $SO(3)$, the rotation angle of $\exp(A)$ is $\|A\|$ (scaled Frobenius norm), so the issue is to see that the open ball $B$ of radius $\pi$ in $\text{Skew}(3\times3)$ maps diffeomorphically to $SO(3)$. (Certainly no larger ball does, since $\exp$ is not 1-1 on the closed ball.) My ideas in introducing the double cover were: (1) The ball in $T_1S^3$ whose image under $\exp$ is the open hemisphere maps diffeomorphically into $S^3$, and (2) The open hemisphere maps diffeomorphically to $SO(3)$, missing the set of half-turns, a.k.a. the set omitted by $\exp(B) \subset SO(3)$....

Comment: Said another way, $\exp:B \to SO(3)$ can be factored into a composition of three diffeomorphisms: the restriction of a linear isomorphism from $\text{Skew}(3\times3)$ to $T_1S^3$, the exponential map to $S^3$ (under which the ball maps to an open hemisphere), and the covering projection from $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ (restricted to the open hemisphere centered at $1$). Admittedly, this may not be the most direct argument, but it seemed so geometrically natural when I saw your question. :)

Comment: It seems to me that what you have proved is that $\exp$ is a diffeomorphism from ball of radius $\pi$ in $\rm{Skew}(3\times 3)$ to $\{R\in SO(3)\,:\,d(R,\rm{Id})<\pi\}$. Am I wrong? Do you think you have an argument that $\exp$ is local diffeomorpism on a bigger ball? If so, please try to clarify just that part.

Comment: Your first claim is right. As for the larger ball, which I'll denote $B_{2\pi}$: Since (i) the ball $B_\pi$ of radius $\pi$ in $\text{Skew}(3\times3)$ corresponds to the ball of radius $\pi/2$ in $T_1S^3$, (ii) the ball of radius $\pi$ in $T_1S^3$ (which corresponds to $B_{2\pi}$) maps diffeomorphically into $S^3$ (missing $-1$), and (iii) $S^3$ projects locally diffeomorphically onto $SO(3)$, it also follows that $B_{2\pi}$ maps locally diffeomorphically to $SO(3)$.

Comment: Numbers (i) and (ii) are fine with me. Number (iii) is problematic. First, these projections from $S^3$ to $SO(3)$ have not been defined. There needs to be showed that these projections are local diffeomorpisms. The closest you have come, as I see it, is that $ad$ is a double cover, and a diffeomorphism from $S^3/\{\pm 1\}$ to $SO(3)$. Second, there needs to be shown that the composition of such projection with the exp from $\rm{Skew}(3\times 3)$ to $S^3$ is really the matrix exponential from the question.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang: sorry for the late comment, but this was very helpful for me. One question: does $ad:S^3\to SO(3)$ yield a Riemannian isometry when $SO(3)$ is given a bi-invariant metric? I'm trying to figure this out, and I would be grateful for a sanity check. In particular, I'm curious whether $ad$ takes all geodesics in $S^3$ to geodesics in $SO(3)$ -- not just the ones emanating from the identity.

Comment: @MatthewKvalheim: Yes, $ad$ identifies antipodal points, and so factors through the antipodal map of $S^{3}$, which is a rotation (an isometry in particular). I believe it's straightforward to check that a bi-invariant metric on $SO(3)$ pulls back to a bi-invariant metric on $S^{3}$,i.e., to a multiple of the round unit metric, which $ad$ maps to the original bi-invariant metric by a Riemannian covering.

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Thanks a lot for the answer! That helps a lot.